# PHP Loop - can't get closing tag to repeat for each group

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I can't work out where I'm going wrong here I'm afraid.

I'm trying to loop through each unique group (each unique layout - let's say theres 'short', 'medium' and 'long' in this dataset) and for each item in that group to print it within the items section.

I've got to the following code, but the problem is the footers are only printing once at the end of all of the code - I need them to print after the items in each section.

```
<?php $seriesgroup = ''; if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
if($row['layout'] != $seriesgroup) {  ?>

    <!-- Print group headers -->

<?php $seriesgroup = $row['layout']; } ?>

        <!-- Print group items -->

<?php } ?>

    <!-- Print footers -->

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: move the footers output in side the loop

Comment: It can't have been that unclear what I was asking, because Pierre has understood it and provided a solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion in your mind about how HTML and PHP interact. The way to do this is to use the statement `echo` from inside the PHP part of your code.

**Edit:** Try this **new** version. The code is cleaner:

```
<?php 
  $previousrow = array ('layout' => ''); 

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
      if($row['layout'] != $previousrow['layout']) { // new group
        if ($previousrow['layout'] !=== '') { // not on first row
          print_footers ($previousrow);
        }
        print_headers ($row);
      } 
      print_group_items ($row);
      $previousrow = $row;
    }
    print_footers ($previousrow);
  } 

function print_group_items ($this_row) {
  echo "  <!-- Print group items -->"\n; // will depend on $this_row
}

function print_headers ($this_row) {
  echo "<!-- Print headers -->\n"; // will depend on $this_row
}

function print_footers ($this_row) {
  echo "<!-- Print footers -->\n"; // will depend on $this_row
}
?>
```

This was the **previous** version and wasn't correct, due to a.o. a tipo in the line containing `print_footers;` without `()`.

```
<?php 
  $seriesgroup = ''; 
  $firstgroup = 1;

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
      if($row['layout'] != $seriesgroup) { 
        if (! $firstgroup) {
          print_footers ();
          $firstgroup = 0;
        }
        print_headers ();
        $seriesgroup = $row['layout']; 
      } 
      print_group_items ($row);
    }
    print_footers;
  } 

function print_group_items ($this_row) {
  echo "  <!-- Print group items -->"\n; // will depend on $this_row
}

function print_headers () {
  echo "<!-- Print headers -->\n";
}

function print_footers () {
  echo "<!-- Print footers -->\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: But this gives me `<!-- Print group headers --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group headers --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group headers --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print footers -->`

Comment: What I need is `<!-- Print group headers --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print footers --><!-- Print group headers --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print footers --><!-- Print group headers --><!-- Print group items --><!-- Print footers -->`

Comment: Anyway, now that the structure of your code is readable, what was not the case before, you can see how the loops have to be nested.

Comment: I edited and corrected my code above, according to your clarification. I suppose the headers and footers are constants.

Comment: This is helpful, but the footer still only comes once at the bottom, after the headers have been printed three times previously. I need three footers to be printed, one after each group of items.

Comment: Yes, this second edit works, and I think I understand the code you have provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this will require you to print the group footer both near the top of the loop if it's not the first one...and at the end of the loop, assuming there was a row.

```
<?php $seriesgroup = ''; if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
if($row['layout'] != $seriesgroup) {  ?>

Print group footer if seriesgroup isn't blank here

<!-- Print group headers -->

<?php $seriesgroup = $row['layout']; } ?>

    <!-- Print group items -->

<?php } ?>

<!-- Print footers -->

<?php } ?>

Print group footer again if series group isn't blank
```

Comment: I think your markup is not displaying correctly.

Comment: No...it wasnt displaying correctly